# Error in getView() when I focus an EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, runtime-error, visibility

In my ListView I have many rows, each with a TextView and a Button. If I click on the TextView, this two Views are made invisible(GONE) and I show an EditText and another Button. This last Button permits to return to the TextView and the previous Button, hiding the Edittext and himself. In other words I switch between this 2 couple of views. 
In the footer of the ListView I have a button that allows to add a new row. When I click on the TextView of this last row are shown, as always, the EditText and the Button. The problem is that when I click on the EditText, i.e. the Edittext gets the focus, most of times this EditText and the relavive Button are hidden, and are shown the TextView with the other Button.

When I debug the code the program never toggle the visibility of any element(or better, in the UiI it does, but the program doesn't meet the line that I wrote with this aim).

I cannot find the error, I leave here the code:

**Class that contains the ListView**:

```
    package fragments;

import [...]


/**
 * La classe FragmentModificaLinea Ã¨ un Fragment che permette di prendere
 * una linea giÃ  presente nel database, e modificare le fermate che essa
 * percorre.
 */
public class FragmentModificaLinea extends Fragment {

    private Context context = null;


private Button btnConfermaModifica = null;
    private Button btnAggiungi = null;
    private Button btnCambiaLinea = null;
    private EditText edtCambiaNome = null;
private EditText edtCambiaCodice = null;
private ListView listViewModifica = null;
private ListView listViewMostra = null;

// Lista di tutte le linee.
private ArrayList<String> contenitoreLinee = null;

// Lista con le linee appartenenti alla fermata e relativo adapter.
private ArrayList<String> fermateDellaLinea = null;
private AdapterModificaLinea adapterFermateDellaLinea = null;

// Inflater per il footer della lista
private LayoutInflater li = null;

// Oggetto che contiene query al db locale.
private Query richiediAlDatabase = null;

// Tag usato nei log.
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = FragmentModificaLinea.class.getSimpleName();

// Salva il codice originale, serve per eliminare la linea.
private String codiceLinea = null;

// La posizione nella listviewmostra dell'elemento da modificare.
private int posizione = 0;

/**
 * Primo metodo che viene chiamato quando creo il fragment. Qui associo
 * il layout al fragment.
 * @param inflater Il layout da utilizzare in questo fragment.
 * @param container Il layout che contiene il fragment.
 * @param savedInstanceState Se si creasse un punto di ripristino dell'activity quando si chiude.
 * @return View
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inserisco il layout di questo fragment.
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment.
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_modifica_linea, container, false);
}

/**
 * Metodo chiamato appena dopo che Ã¨ stato istanziato il layout. Ottengo gli oggetti in esso presenti.
 * @param view Tutte le view nel layout.
 * @param savedInstanceState Se si creasse un punto di ripristino dell'activity quando si chiude.
 */
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    context = getActivity();        
    richiediAlDatabase = new Query(context);
    li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    // Carico tutte le linee dal database locale.
    contenitoreLinee = richiediAlDatabase.caricaLinee();        
    // Imposto la listView che mostra le linee.
    listViewMostra = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewModificaLineaMostraLinee);
    listViewMostra.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contenitoreLinee));
    listViewMostra.setEmptyView(getView().findViewById(R.id.empty_list_item));
    // Imposto la ListView; ci aggiungo come footer i bottoni al fondo del layout:
    // aggiungi una fermata e conferma linea.
    listViewModifica = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewModificaLinea);
    LinearLayout footer = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.footer_list_view, null);
    btnConfermaModifica = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btnConfermaModifica);
    btnAggiungi = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btnAggiungi);
    listViewModifica.addFooterView(footer);
    // Aggiungo come header ciÃ² che mi permette di modifica nome, codice linea
    // e di cambiare linea che si sta modificando.
    LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.header_list_view, null);
    btnCambiaLinea = (Button) header.findViewById(R.id.btnCambiaLinea);
    edtCambiaCodice = (EditText) header.findViewById(R.id.edtCambiaCodice);
    edtCambiaNome = (EditText) header.findViewById(R.id.edtCambiaNome);
    listViewModifica.addHeaderView(header);

    listViewMostra.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            posizione = position;

            // Setto l'adapter alla ListView.
            fermateDellaLinea = richiediAlDatabase.caricaFermateDellaLinea(((String) listViewMostra.getItemAtPosition(posizione)).split(" Cod: ")[1]);
            adapterFermateDellaLinea = new AdapterModificaLinea(context, R.layout.elemento_modifica_linea, fermateDellaLinea);
            listViewModifica.setAdapter(adapterFermateDellaLinea);
            // Rendo visibile la ListView.
            listViewModifica.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
            // Inizializzo i valori nell'header: nome e codice.
            edtCambiaNome.setText(((String) listViewMostra.getItemAtPosition(posizione)).split(" - Cod: ")[0]);
            edtCambiaCodice.setText(((String) listViewMostra.getItemAtPosition(posizione)).split(" - Cod: ")[1]);
            // Salvo il codice della linea così posso poi eliminarla.
            codiceLinea = ((String) listViewMostra.getItemAtPosition(posizione)).split(" Cod: ")[1];
            // Disabiliti gli oggetti per la ricerca della linea.
            listViewMostra.setVisibility(ListView.GONE);

        }
    });


    // Aggiunge una fermata alla ListView.
    btnAggiungi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Controllo che non stia modificando giÃ  un'altra linea.
            if(!adapterFermateDellaLinea.isStoModificandoUnaFermata())
                // Se fermateDellaLinea fosse vuoto andrebbe in errore la prossima if,
                // quindi si aggiunge senza ulteriori controlli.
                if(!fermateDellaLinea.isEmpty())
                    // Se l'ultima riga Ã¨ ancora da inserire.
                    if(!fermateDellaLinea.get(fermateDellaLinea.size() - 1).equals("Nuova fermata")){
                        // Codice uguale all'else sottostante.
                        fermateDellaLinea.add("Nuova fermata");
                        adapterFermateDellaLinea.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else Toast.makeText(context, "Inserire prima la fermata appena aggiunta.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else{
                    fermateDellaLinea.add("Nuova fermata");
                    adapterFermateDellaLinea.notifyDataSetChanged();                    
                }
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Confermare la fermata che si sta tentando di modificare.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    // Bottone che permette di caricare la linea aggiornata.
    btnConfermaModifica.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Se l'ultima fermata Ã¨ giÃ  stata inserita.
            if(!fermateDellaLinea.get(fermateDellaLinea.size() - 1).equals("Nuova fermata")){
                // Se non si sta tentando di modificare una fermata.
                if(!adapterFermateDellaLinea.isStoModificandoUnaFermata())
                    // Permette di caricare la linea.
                    new UpdateLinea().execute();
                else Toast.makeText(context, "Confermare la fermata che si sta tentando di modificare.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else Toast.makeText(context, "Inserire l'ultima fermata con un suggerimento.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    // Questo bottone nasconde la listView e abilita la ricerca di una nuova linea da modificare.
    btnCambiaLinea.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Rendo visibigli gli elementi per la ricerca.
            listViewMostra.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);

            // Nascondo la ListView.
            listViewModifica.setVisibility(ListView.GONE);

            // Ripulisco le EditText.
            edtCambiaCodice.setText("");
            edtCambiaNome.setText("");
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Il compito di questa classe Ã¨ quello di aggiornare la linea. Per far
 * ciÃ² prima la cancella dai database e poi la ricarica con i nuovi dati.
 * Non si usano due AsyncTask diversi per evitare il caso in cui, non essendo
 * sincronizzati, si inseriscano dei record prima che vengano eliminati.
 */
class UpdateLinea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Tag usato nei log.
    private final String TAG = UpdateLinea.class.getSimpleName();

    private String ELIMINA_LINEA = GlobalClass.getDominio() + "Upload/eliminaLinea.php";
    private String CARICA_LINEA = GlobalClass.getDominio() + "Upload/caricaLinea.php";

    private String nomeLineaScelta = edtCambiaNome.getText().toString();
    private String codiceLineaScelta = edtCambiaCodice.getText().toString();

    JSONObject jsonElimina = null;
    JSONObject jsonCarica = null;
    List<NameValuePair> paramsCarica = null;

    /**
     * Metodo che viene eseguito prima di doInBackground.
     * Avvio il ProgressDialog.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Creo e mostro il ProgressDialog.
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Aggiornamento Fermata...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Questo metodo esegue il download.
     * @param voids
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        String codLinea = codiceLinea;
        // Creazione dei parametri.
        List<NameValuePair> paramsElimina = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        paramsElimina.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CodLinea", codLinea));

        // Richiesta della pagina .php.
        jsonElimina = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                ELIMINA_LINEA, "POST", paramsElimina);


        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        // Creazione dei parametri.
        // A differenza della classe FragmentAggiungiLinea, i parametri
        // li creo dentro all'AsyncTask perchÃ¨ i controlli li faccio
        // giÃ  durante l'inserimento, e non quando si conferma l'invio
        // dei dati.
        paramsCarica = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        paramsCarica.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NomeLinea", nomeLineaScelta));
        paramsCarica.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CodLinea", codiceLineaScelta));
        for (String fermata : fermateDellaLinea) {
            paramsCarica.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Fermate[]", fermata.split(" - Cod: ")[1]));
        }

        // Richiesta della pagina .php.
        jsonCarica = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                CARICA_LINEA, "POST", paramsCarica);

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo eseguito dopo doInBackground. Chiudo il ProgressDialog.
     * @param risultato E' il risultato del .php.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Chiudo il ProgressDialog.
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // Aggiorno il database locale.
        try {

            // Se la linea Ã¨ sia stata eliminata che aggiunta con successo.
            if(jsonElimina.getInt(GlobalClass.getTagSuccess()) != 0)
                if(jsonCarica.getInt(GlobalClass.getTagSuccess()) != 0){


                // Ottengo il database locale.
                DatabaseLocale db = new DatabaseLocale(context);
                SQLiteDatabase dbScrivibile = db.getWritableDatabase();

                // Cancello da linea e tratta.
                dbScrivibile.delete(DatabaseLocale.getTableNameLinea(), 
                        DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea() + " = '" + codiceLineaScelta + "'", null);                    
                dbScrivibile.delete(DatabaseLocale.getTableNameTratta(), 
                        DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea() + " = '" + codiceLineaScelta + "'", null);

                /// AGGIUNGO LA LINEA
                ContentValues valori = new ContentValues();
                valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea(), codiceLineaScelta);
                valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagNomeLinea(), nomeLineaScelta);
                valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceCapolinea(), fermateDellaLinea.get(0));
                dbScrivibile.insert(DatabaseLocale.getTableNameLinea(), null, valori);

                for (int i = 0; i < paramsCarica.size(); i++) {
                    BasicNameValuePair valore = ((BasicNameValuePair) paramsCarica.get(i));
                    if(valore.getName() == "Fermate[]" && i != (paramsCarica.size() - 1)){                          
                        valori = new ContentValues();
                        valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea(), codiceLineaScelta);
                        valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceFermata(), valore.getValue());
                        valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagSuccessiva(), ((BasicNameValuePair) paramsCarica.get(i + 1)).getValue());
                        dbScrivibile.insert(DatabaseLocale.getTableNameTratta(), null, valori);
                    }else if(i == (paramsCarica.size() - 1)){                           
                        valori = new ContentValues();
                        valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceLinea(), codiceLineaScelta.toString());
                        valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagCodiceFermata(), valore.getValue());
                        valori.put(DatabaseLocale.getTagSuccessiva(), 0);
                        dbScrivibile.insert(DatabaseLocale.getTableNameTratta(), null, valori);
                    }
                }

                // Chiudo le connessioni.
                dbScrivibile.close();
                db.close();

                Toast.makeText(context, "Linea modificata con successo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else Toast.makeText(context, "Errore nel caricamento della linea", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else Toast.makeText(context, "Errore eliminando la linea", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Errore durante l'aggiornamento della linea nel database locale.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    }

}
```

**Adapter of listView**, here I toggle the visibility:

```
package fragments;

import [...]

/**
 * Questa classe ha il compito di gestire tutte le linee
 * della ListView, e quindi il loro comportamento. Ogni linea 
 * ha 4 Views, di cui ne mostra solo 2 per volta.
 * All'inizio mostra il nome della fermata ed il bottone per 
 * eliminarla. Se si clicca sul nome della linea queste due
 * Views vengono nascoste e viene mostrata una EditText
 * per inserire la nuova fermata ed un bottone per confermare.
 * @author giacomotb
 *
 */
public class AdapterModificaLinea extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context = null;
    private LayoutInflater li = null;
private ArrayList<String> fermateDellaLinea = null;

// Variabile che indica se in almeno una riga
// si sta modificando la fermata(Ã¨ mostrata 
// l'EditText.
private boolean stoModificandoUnaFermata = false;

// Il layout che viene usato per ogni riga.
private int layoutResourceId = 0; 

// Oggetto che contiene query al db locale.
private Query richiediAlDatabase = null;


/**
 * Classe statica che permette di evitare ripetuti
 * findViewById(), e risparmia il 15% del tempo.
 * http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance
 * http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder
 *
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtCambiaFermata;
    AutoCompleteTextView actModificaFermata;
    Button btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea;
    Button btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea;
}

/**
 * Costruttore.
 * @param context
 * @param resource
 * @param fermate
 */
public AdapterModificaLinea(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> fermate) {
    super(context, resource, fermate);
    this.context = context;
    layoutResourceId = resource;
    this.fermateDellaLinea = fermate;   
    li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

/**
 * Metodo che crea la row quando si disegna la ListView.
 * Assegna anche i listener ai suoi elementi.
 */
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    richiediAlDatabase = new Query(context);

    // Tutte le fermare nel database locale.
    final ArrayList<String> tutteLeFermate = richiediAlDatabase.caricaFermate();

    // Permette di riutilizzare le View che sono fuori dallo schermo
    // per risparmiare tempo.
    // http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = li.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

        // configure view holder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCambiaFermata = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCambiaFermata);
        viewHolder.actModificaFermata = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.actModificaFermata);
        viewHolder.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea);
        viewHolder.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea);         
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    if(!stoModificandoUnaFermata){
        // Setto la visibilitÃ  di default.
        holder.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
        holder.actModificaFermata.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.GONE);
        holder.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtCambiaFermata.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        // Aggiungo il testo alla TextView
        holder.txtCambiaFermata.setText(fermateDellaLinea.get(position));
        // Aggiungo l'adapter all'AutoCompleteTextView.
        holder.actModificaFermata.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, tutteLeFermate));            
    }

    // Se si preme sulla textview la scambio con una all'AutoCompleteTextView per cambiare fermata.
    holder.txtCambiaFermata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               

            // Se non sto giÃ  modificando un'altra fermata.
            if(!stoModificandoUnaFermata){
                // Dichiaro che sto modificando una fermata.
                stoModificandoUnaFermata = true;

                // Assegno all'AutoComplete.. il testo della TextView nascosta.
                holder.actModificaFermata.setText(holder.txtCambiaFermata.getText().toString());
                // Cambio visibilitÃ  agli elementi.
                holder.txtCambiaFermata.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                holder.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                holder.actModificaFermata.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.VISIBLE);
                holder.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);


                // Listener al bottone che conferma la modifica della fermata.
                holder.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                        
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // Non sto piÃ¹ modificando alcuna riga.
                        stoModificandoUnaFermata = false;

                        // Se la fermata Ã¨ una di quelle consigliate.
                        if(tutteLeFermate.contains(holder.actModificaFermata.getText().toString()))
                            // Se non Ã¨ presente tra quelle giÃ  inserite
                            if(!fermateDellaLinea.contains(holder.actModificaFermata.getText().toString())
                                    // Ma la posizione non Ã¨ la stessa di quella che si sta modificando,
                                    // nel caso in cui si reinserisca la fermata che si voleva modificare.
                                    || fermateDellaLinea.indexOf(holder.actModificaFermata.getText().toString()) == position){

                                // Cambio la fermata nella lista a cui fa riferimento la ListView.
                                fermateDellaLinea.set(position, holder.actModificaFermata.getText().toString());
                                // Notifico i cambiamenti.
                                AdapterModificaLinea.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                // Cambio le visibilitÃ .
                                holder.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
                                holder.actModificaFermata.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.GONE);
                                holder.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                                holder.txtCambiaFermata.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

                            }else Toast.makeText(context, "Fermata giÃ  presente: prima di inserirla eliminare la medesima fermata dalla lista"
                                        , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else Toast.makeText(context, "La fermata deve assumere uno dei valori suggeriti."
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });             
            }else Toast.makeText(context, "Confermate la fermata che si sta modificando."
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    // Bottone che permette di eliminare una data riga e la sua fermata.
    holder.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fermateDellaLinea.remove(position);
            AdapterModificaLinea.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public boolean isStoModificandoUnaFermata() {
    return stoModificandoUnaFermata;
    }


}
```

Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to replace this pieace of code
 if(convertView == null){
        convertView = li.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

        // configure view holder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCambiaFermata = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCambiaFermata);
        viewHolder.actModificaFermata = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.actModificaFermata);
        viewHolder.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea);
        viewHolder.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea);         
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

With this

```
ViewHolder viewHolder;
 if(convertView == null){
            convertView = li.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

        // configure view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCambiaFermata = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCambiaFermata);
        viewHolder.actModificaFermata = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.actModificaFermata);
        viewHolder.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminaFermataModificaLinea);
        viewHolder.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnModificaFermataInModificaLinea);         
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: In the second piece of code, into the else clausole, you mean viewHolder? Or holder? If you mean holder, if convertView == null, when holder will be assigned? I changed the code thinking of the firts hypotesis and it still does not work. The views doesn't toggle.